# Google Analytics "tracking code mismatch" when using different analytics ids on different versions of a product

Tags: google-analytics

**Background**

I have a single web app, which is accessible via a webview, across 4 different models of television set-top boxes.

When the app loads on a set-top box, it initialises Google Analytics with a  tracking ID specific to the model of set-top it is running on.

**Example**

E.g. `ga('create', gaTrackingID, 'auto');`

With `gaTrackingID` being a variable, taken from a config file, specific to the model of set top box that the app is running on.

Data is then stored within Google Analytics in one of the 4 separate properties for each model of set-top box.

**The Problem**

However, **all 4 properties share the same default URL**. This is causing Google Analytics to generate a “Tracking Code Mismatch” notification.

I'd like to fix this issue:

1. Is there any way to use multiple Tracking ID's on the same domain in Google Analytics, as a route to resolving this issue?
2. If not, what other options might be available to me?

Comment: Is the web app running on each set top box?   Or the the web-app running in a data center and the set-top boxes are contacting it?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's the latter - the web app is running in a data center and the set-top boxes are contacting it.